# Position of Content Types

Tags: content-type

Whats the difference in creating a Content Type in the Root Site collection to that of a subweb?

I've noticed when created at Root lovel its available to all sub-webs wheras if I create at web level its only available to sites below.

Is there any difference when it comes to associating workflows to Content Types or anything else?

I think when a root CT is used in a subweb, SP makes a local copy at subweb level, so it behaves as if the CT is locally created. Is this true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is really a matter of scope.  You should define it at the widest scope that you would reasonably think to use it.  Generally for Site Collections, I encourage people to manage the content types at the root (or on the central Content Type Hub in 2010).

If you have a one off content type, then it is ok to define it at the sub-site.  In situations where you have a giant shared, site collection then permissions may play a part in the decision as a sub-site owner would have permission to create one there, but not at the root.